# SSIS SQL Azure simple package fails without error message

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

I have created a package in SSIS 2012 which has one data flow task, which uses an OLE DB Source from a SQL Server on a VM and writes the data to an OLE DB Destination on SQL Azure. The package breaks with a read X on the OLE DB Destination, **but there are no Error message in the Error Window**. I have also looked for, and been unable to find, SYSSSISLOG tables on both source and target servers. 
Can anyone offer suggestions on how to further troubleshoot this package?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an ADO.Net destination with SSIS rather than OleDB.  OleDB is not supported on Azure DB.  While ODBC will work, ADO.Net will likely be faster.